# How to change ctrl+del behaviour in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ckeditor

I have to restrict user from deleting such words that are in a particular HTML tag (consider I have a custom tag) in a textarea.

```html
<div>
    You can Delete Me
    <t>
        DontDeleteMe
    </t>
</div>
```

The words which are not in a `t` tag can be deleted.
I tried few logics nothing helps.

Is there any possibilities to get the selection range of <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>del</kbd> keywords do?

```js
case 46:
  { //DEL
    if (range.startOffset == startNode.getLength()) {
      var ancestor = endNode.$;
      while (ancestor != null) {
        var next = ancestor.nextSibling;
        if (next != null) {
          console.log("Next = " + next);
          var node = new CKEDITOR.dom.node(next);
          cancelEvent = node.isReadOnly();
          break;
        }
        ancestor = ancestor.parentNode;
      }
    }
    break;
  }
```

Comment: Show us what you have tried yourself.. t tag?

Comment: I have posted my code in jsfiddle and the link is [https://jsfiddle.net/arunkumar1991/ayqwmyL4/] @Krzysztof janiszewski .The above code i done for restricting delete key,i will prevent default action from another method that i dint included in my fiddle

Comment: t tag, is my custom html tag.u may take it as ro tag also i just used t tag for example.you can consider it as <hello> tag.its just a custom tag

Comment: Wonder how the world of HTML would look if everyone used custom tags.

Comment: Is there any way to acheive my requirement??@CarstenLøvboAndersen

Comment: instead of custom tag just use for example `span` and add a specific class

Comment: @ArunKumar this fiddle does not reproduce your problem. Please update it so that it represents your problem.

Comment: ok,lets forget about the custom tags,when the user clicks ctrl+del,is there any way to get which portions of the text are going to deleted.So that i can get the node name of the element and prevent the deletion,i dont have anyother codes other than the code in fiddle @KrzysztofJaniszewski

Comment: @ArunKumar this is only a tiny bit of js code. Don't tell me you don't have more. Look at my seggested edit to your post, I copied your fiddle to snippet here.

Comment: @ArunKumar I'm rying to help you, but I can't if you won't cooperate

Comment: You could set [`user-select:none`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/user-select) in css on text you don't want highlighted (and subsequently deleted)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, your description is quite poor when it comes to describing exactly what you need with examples so nobody really knows what you want to happen to the text.

Here's my [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uceLcwux/10/) I just made.

It notes `selected text` and the `ID` of the first highlighted text container.

> Select the text and press `CTRL + Del`.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a text area, you can just let the user delete it but then copy it inside again. But why use a text area if the user shouldnt interfere with it? Did i misunderstand the feature you want?

```
$(document).on('keydown', function(evt) {
  if (evt.ctrlKey && evt.keyCode == 46) {             // Ctrl + Del key pressed
    if (evt.target.id == 'customTextArea') {          // Custom tag selected
      $('#customTextArea').text('Don't delete me!');  // Copy old text in text area
    } 
  }
});
```